# Eloquent relation pivot table with table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I read the laravel documentation but I couldn't understand very well.
I have this structure on my database.

PriceTable - which contains info about the period of promotional prices and the default price.

Product - which contains info about products.

and PriceTable_Product - which contains the foreign keys of Product and PriceTable and the respective price.

Example:

```
PriceTable        |  PriceTable_Product                 |  Product
id |  description |  PriceTable_id | Product_id | price |  product_id| name  
1  |  default     |    1           |    1       | 5.00  |   1        | test
2  |  promotional |    2           |    1       | 3.50  |
```

And at the Order table I can have multiples products, so I want to know if it is possible to relation Order table, with the pivot table PriceTable_Product, because I need the information of which table belongs the price when the product was sold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you may define the relations between Product and PriceTable.

**Product model (App\Product.php)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Product extends Model {
    protected $table = 'products';
    //if the default primary key isn't 'id' you may use $primaryKey
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
    public function pricetables() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PriceTable');
    }
}
```

**PriceTable model (App\PriceTable.php)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

class PriceTable extends Model {
    protected $table = 'pricetable';
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

If you created the relations then you can use:

```
$product = App\Product::find(1);

foreach ($product->pricetables as $pricetable) {
    echo $pricetable->pivot->description;
}
```

Comment: thanks, if I have an Order model where I need to get pricetables info how can I do that? Is the same way you did?

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone'll still see this, but this question is *almost* exactly what I'm looking for, except that I need to show (using this example) the value for PriceTable_Product.price.  When I access $pricetable->pivot it only has the ids and not the other columns in that table.  How can I show that field too?